# TS interface for dynamic key in object

Tags: typescript, interface

I would like to write the proper interface for this object. The key of step should be dynamic and the value is boolean. This is the object:

```
const obj = {
  A: {
    step: {
      a: true,
      b: true,
      c: true,
    },
  },
  B: {
    step: {
      a: true,
      d: true,
    },
  },
  C: {
    step: {
      e: true,
      f: true,
      g: true,
    },
  },
}
```

So far I have tried this, but I still got an error.

```
interface OBJ_INTERFACE {
  side: {
    step: {
      [key: string]: boolean,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And the error is? Also not clear what is `side` in the `interface`

Comment: The side is A, B or C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract `Step` type and reuse it in interface:

```
type Side = {
  step: {
    [key: string]: boolean,
  }
};

interface OBJ_INTERFACE {
  A: Side;
  B: Side;
  C: Side;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgE2gXigbwFBSgZ2BMALnS2ygG0BrCEYvAJzgDsBzAXWICMB7bgGwgBDJgBpSAXwziA3BgzN89AGaCAxtADyAIQBSAfQCSAOQAqAUQBKAMQCCAYTMlsN4vCSzsW14ggeod73cpOVVuJjwobk4AK2JtfWNza3tHVExnYnSyPAJM0jIoQWJgegBXCDEC7E5isor8slVa8sqycVb20i8nbPwiHoKiqBKWhuwEZvqCzuwZ-zyCnP6sgohJ1oKldbGoFm3pjrFJIA)

---

Or define a mapped type:

```
type OBJ_INTERFACE = {
  [P in 'A' | 'B' | 'C']: {
    step: {
      [key: string]: boolean,
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gQgKQPoEkByAVAogJQGICCAwllALxQDeAUFFANoAKUAlgHZQDkBnUAPlzi8BnIpwC6ALiq06UAM7AIYaTTlz6AawghpigE7sA5lKgAjAPYWANhACGbADSy6AX1nv31AMYW2iqAszACtpeGR0bHxiUgo1KAJVFwUlFRl1OjtpYH0AVwhnDPNsvILkum8S-MK5Vxq62Tgk9UVlZoysqBzq8qgAEyqy9Qa3GqJ2ula0+PUIQZr1ADN53qMV4frndyA)

Answer (score 1):

You don't detail the error, so I can only assume it stems from trying to use the interface as such:

```js
const obj: OBJ_INTERFACE = {
  A: {
    step: {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

In which case, your interface doesn't account for the `side` property being dynamically named as `'A' | 'B' | 'C'`.

Try making `side` dynamic as well:

```js
interface OBJ_INTERFACE {
    [key: string]: {
      step: {
        [key: string]: boolean
    }
  }
}
```